# php array using a function during the loop

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

i have an array

```
array:3 [▼
  "scoring_average" => array:4 [▼
    0 => "76.402"
    1 => "72.05616203703711"
    2 => "68.208"
    3 => 76.0
  ]
  "front_9_scoring_average" => array:4 [▼
    0 => "41.5"
    1 => "36.15309523809525"
    2 => "33.25"
    3 => "38.0"
  ]
  "back_9_scoring_average" => array:4 [▼
    0 => "39.75"
    1 => "36.078605442176865"
    2 => "33.17"
    3 => "38.0"
  ]
]
```

I need to pass the 4 items in each element ("scoring_average" e.g) to a function which does some comparison and returns a string based on the result.

```
Comparison::CompareLower($BottomStat, $AverageStat, $TopStat, 
$playerStat)

$BottomStat = "76.402", $AverageStat = "72.05616203703711", $TopStat = 
"68.208", $playerStat = 76.0
```

How can I loop through this array and pass these four values to a function, get the result and then move onto the next array in the array?

Comment: it's unclear what you are trying to achieve here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$array = array(
    'scoring_average' => array(
        '76.402',
        '72.05616203703711',
        '68.208',
        '76.0'
    ),
    'front_9_scoring_average' => array(
        '41.5',
        '36.15309523809525',
        '33.25',
        '38.0'
    ),
    'back_9_scoring_average' => array(
        '39.75',
        '36.078605442176865',
        '33.17',
        '38.0'
    )
);

// can be transformed into $array as $key=>$single if you need scoring_average, front_9_scoring_average, ... as $key
foreach ($array as $single) {
    $yourResult = Comparison::CompareLower($single[0], $single[1], $single[2], $single[3]);
    // do whatever you like with $yourResult
}
```

Foreach is the function you are looking for. http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: Thanks. Works with the array above. Will be adding many more arrays to the above array (same structure) but It works. Thanks!!

Comment: I have to mention that what Artem Ilchenko said is also right and can be a better solution, depending on the case, so consider carefully and always check the official documentation :-)

Answer (score 1):

for call function with array of params use:

```
$result = call_user_func_array('Comparison::CompareLower', $row);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a `for`, based on your array

```
for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($array); $i++) {
    $BottomStat = $array[i][0];
    $AverageStat = $array[i][1];
    $TopStat = $array[i][2];
    $playerStat = $array[i][3]
    $returnString = Comparison::CompareLower($BottomStat, $AverageStat, $TopStat, $playerStat)
}
```

I'm not sure if that's what you mean.

Comment: Is there a performance increase or something for using a `for` loop instead of a `foreach` loop? This for loop will call `sizeof()` on every iteration of the loop, which is not efficient.

Comment: It will, you could use a `foreach` loop if you want. Depending on the size of your array it may affect the performance, but it needs to be very big.

Comment: You could use the function `array_map` to iterate through your array and change the values, it is a little bit more efficient but you really need to have a huge array to make a diffrence.